# Get nth substring of string with common delimiter

Tags: java, groovy, substring, indexof

I'm working in a groovy web console and want to get the 3rd and last substring that is delimited by /. I've been able to get the last substring using lastIndexOf() and could get the first if desired, but for the life of me I haven't been able to find anything quick and simple to get the index of the second and third occurrence of / so that I can extract the third substring. My desired output from my code below would be:

Produce
Apples

In my sample I am currently printing the pathDelim just for sanity check so ignore why that's there. Sorry if this is a simple question but I'm new to groovy and primarily come from a SQL background where this would be an easy and quick task. Thanks in advance!

```
productPath = "Store/Grocery/Produce/Apples";

int pathDelim = productPath.lastIndexOf('/');
itemName = (productPath.substring(pathDelim + 1));

println pathDelim;
println itemName;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered just splitting the string?

```
​productPath.split('/')[2, 3].each {
    println it
}
```

Prints your desired output:

```
Produce
Apples
```

If you need all the indexes you can do

```
​productPath.findIndexValues { it == '/' }
```

Which returns

```
[5, 13, 21]
```

Comment: See code run live at Ideone.com [in Groovy](https://ideone.com/SYYxmG) and [in Java](https://ideone.com/ah8dnU).

Comment: This solution seems like it will work to get the Produce result. Thank you. I don't think I can rely on it to get the last string since I may have scenarios where there are more entries "Store/Pharmacy/Medicine/Generic/Ibuprofen" for example I would want Medicine and Ibuprofen. I can get the solution I need with the information you provided. Thank you, @tim_yates!

Comment: So you want the 3rd and last? Use `[2, -1]`

Comment: Correct and thanks again. That'll keep my code more consistent.

Comment: No worries, have fun!